# How do I optimize the revenue to have a positive Net Present Value Python

Tags: python, optimization

I have a code that already calculates the NPV and IRR of the investment, which is negative. However, I would like to optimize the revenue column which would yield a positive NPV. How do I go about this?

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format
for i in range (1,30):
    inv_table.iloc[i,0] = i + 1
    inv_table.iloc[i,1] = inv_table.iloc[(i-1), 5]
    inv_table.iloc[i,2] = loan_payment
    inv_table.iloc[i,3] = inv_table.iloc[i,1] * interest
    inv_table.iloc[i,4] = loan_payment - (inv_table.iloc[i,1] * interest)
    inv_table.iloc[i,5] = inv_table.iloc[i,1] - (loan_payment - (inv_table.iloc[i,1] * interest))
    inv_table.iloc[i,6] = tot_cap / year
    inv_table.iloc[i,7] = inv_table.iloc[(i - 1) ,7] * (1 + index)
    inv_table.iloc[i,8] = inv_table.iloc[(i - 1) ,8] * (1 + index)

inv_table['terminal_value'] = np.where(inv_table['Year'] == year, (tot_cap * residual_value), 0)
inv_table['financial_cost'] = inv_table['Payments'] + inv_table['Interest']
inv_table['EBITDA'] = inv_table['Revenues'] + inv_table['terminal_value'] - inv_table['operating_cost']
inv_table['opr_result'] = inv_table['EBITDA'] - inv_table['Depreciation']
inv_table['EBT'] = inv_table['opr_result'] - inv_table['Interest']
inv_table['Tax'] = np.where(inv_table['EBT'] > 0, (tax * inv_table['EBT']) , 0)
inv_table['EAT'] = inv_table['EBT'] - inv_table['Tax']
inv_table['cash_flow'] = inv_table['EAT'] + inv_table['Depreciation'] - inv_table['Payments']
cashflows = inv_table['cash_flow'].values.tolist()
cashflows.insert(0, -tot_cap)
NPV = round(npf.npv(WACC, cashflows))
IRR = round(npf.irr( cashflows), 2)
```

Above is the code that was written to get the NPV and IRR, I want to get the optimal solution for the revenue that would make the NPV positive with a condition:

```
current revenue  = 13.9/TEU
Max revenue = 41.01
total teu = 100000
```

the condition is that the current revenue cannot be greater than the mac revenue. Hence, I need a code that automatically selects a revenue value that would yield a positive NPV

[see below for the sample data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwJ1T.png)

[and the NPV and IRR outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8v6l.png)

At the moment, the NPV is negative, I would like to loop through the current revenue variable such that it gives me a value that would give a positive NPV. In doing so, the revenue variable cannot exceed the Max revenue variable. I hope this information helps?

Comment: Your question needs some detail and focus.  Right now it is a bunch of table references without any data.  Perhaps you could whittle this down to an essential, small data table and refine your question, and show what effort you have done to solve the problem to date

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I edited the post. At the moment, I don't know how to code this. I just need pointers on where to begin. Thanks

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, a minimal dataset that can be copied. Something that others can recreate at their end and see exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Right now, for example, it is not clear whether you are trying to optimize for one revenue value or multiple revenues. If it is multiple values, are they somehow linked to each other?